# Add application to Ubuntu's root's autorun

Tags: linux, ubuntu, autorun

I need to add my lampp to autorun. Where shuld I put this command `/opt/lampp/lampp start` to be runned from root on system bootup?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Add it to /etc/rc.local
It will be run as root on startup.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a Startup Programs tab in Systems\Preferences\Sessions. You just add your command there. To make it run as root, you need to give the file itself root ownership, by doing a [`chown`](http://nersp.nerdc.ufl.edu/~dicke3/nerspcs/chown.html) on it.